# FreeTSD and MS SQL instance on virtualbox

Tags: python, sql-server-2005, virtualbox, pyodbc, freetds

I have Windows installed on virtualbox. On this Windows I have instance of MS SQL called "InsertGT".

I'm using python package "pypyodbc" to connect to this instance.
My code looks like this:

```
 import pypydbc
 pypyodbc.connect(u'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=localhost\\INSERTGT;DATABASE=test;UID=sa;PWD=;PORT=1433')
```

On Windows (inside my virtualbox) this works flawless.

On host (in Ubuntu) i have forwarded port 1433 to virtualbox. My code can't connect to instance INSERTGT.

Long story, short:

On Ubuntu this works:

```
pypyodbc.connect(u'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;UID=sa;PWD=;PORT=1433')
```

and this doesn't:

```
pypyodbc.connect(u'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=localhost\\INSERTGT;DATABASE=test;UID=sa;PWD=;PORT=1433')
```

Can somebody tell me way?